# Nesting Layouts?

Tags: android

Does android api 19 have a problem with nesting layouts?

I created a nested layout that runs perfectly on Android 7 but the app crashes on Android versions below 5. What could be the problem?

Comment: We can't say unless we see the crash logs. Please post them.

Comment: A sample XML and the vital details like compilesdk version and other details would help to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using API features that aren't supported on these versions. Try looking for errors, and check your minimum SDK version in the app level gradle script.